# How to create multiline editable digital signal/square wave in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a task that need a page to edit digital signal/square wave and save them. But the data is so big that controls cant perform well under millions data.

As shown in the picture,i tried to use datagrid,and datagrid can perform well when the columns is limited in around 100, but the task will have millions of columns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmKEE.png)
I wonder if there have other solution,Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

this is exemple code :

```
    <Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Digital Signal Waveform" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="signalCanvas" Background="White" Width="500" Height="200" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This example uses a Polyline to represent the digital signal on a Canvas. Mouse events are used to allow users to draw and edit the waveform. You can further customize this example based on your specific requirements.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Polyline signalLine;
        private PointCollection signalPoints;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeSignal();
        }

        private void InitializeSignal()
        {
            signalLine = new Polyline
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            signalPoints = new PointCollection();
            signalLine.Points = signalPoints;

            signalCanvas.Children.Add(signalLine);
            signalCanvas.MouseDown += SignalCanvas_MouseDown;
            signalCanvas.MouseMove += SignalCanvas_MouseMove;
            signalCanvas.MouseUp += SignalCanvas_MouseUp;
        }

        private void SignalCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AddPoint(e.GetPosition(signalCanvas));
        }

        private void SignalCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                AddPoint(e.GetPosition(signalCanvas));
            }
        }

        private void SignalCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Perform any cleanup or finalization if needed
        }

        private void AddPoint(Point point)
        {
            signalPoints.Add(new Point(point.X, signalCanvas.ActualHeight / 2));
            signalLine.Points = signalPoints;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer. It is possible to add squares or ellipses to the canvas with event handlers. These can serve as control handles that the user can drag and manipulate.